# How to override Swagger's default produces header value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger version 2.4.0 and Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE and have an application with several API endpoints and with default Swagger configuration having default produces header value set to `application/json`.

### SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES = ImmutableSet.of(
            "application/json"
    );

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
                .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES);
    }
}
```

And with API endpoint set up being.

### ApiEndpoint.java

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "/transform", protocols = "http, https")
@RequestMapping(value = "/transform")
public interface ApiEndpoint {

    @POST
    @RequestMapping(value = "/text", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Transform to plain text", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @CrossOrigin
    String transformToText(@RequestBody TransformRequest transformRequest) throws Exception;
}
```

Now I want this endpoint to produce response with content type being only plain text, but SwaggerConfig adds `application/json` option as default one. So in order to correctly use this endpoint I would need to change Response Content Type from `application/json` to `text/plain` every time, which would get annoying pretty quick considering that this endpoint is used for testing. Is there a way to override SwaggerConfig or to add a parameter so text/plain is the only option or at least to set the text/plain as the default option only for this one endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to define the response content type in your requestMapping annotation.

That is,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/text", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

will be replaced by,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/text", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")
```

Means, you have to define in requestMapping that what type of content this mapping will going to return.

**Note :**  Will be good practice if you use

```
@PostMapping(value = "/text", produces="text/plain")
```

Hope, the solution will work fine.

Comment: This solution is not exactly what I need. Currently, I already have both application/json and text/plain as options, but application/json is chosen as default in swagger-ui. So in other to correctly use the endpoint I'd need to change it every time when reloading page and see it being quite annoying for me and my team. I'm just wondering if there is a way to force swagger-ui to display text/plain as only option for this endpoint or at least show it as default option.
P.S. Good point on @PostMapping note, I'll keep it in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just specifying type in order in the endpoint annotation, example:

atribute **produces** receive an array, so you can put more than one type

```
@PostMapping(value = "/text", produces = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
```

I advise removing produces in **@Bean**, as its API contains endpoint that did not always follow the standard idea of "**application/json**"